# WPF Drag-and-Drop between ListBoxes in different UserControls

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop, listbox, listboxitem

This is the structure of my application:

- Main Window has two ContentControls
- Each ContentControl has a UserControl
- Each UserControl has a ListBox

So graphically speaking, the user is presented with a Window with two ListBoxes: one with products and the other a shopping cart.

I want to enable drag-and-drop functionality among these two ListBoxes; i.e products can be dragged into the shopping cart.

I have seen examples of drag-and-drop between ListBoxes on the same window. But is it possible to drag and drop between UserControls?

I have looked at [an example](http://www.beacosta.com/blog/?p=53); is there a simpler way?

I came across a simple drag drop solution in Expression Blend; I tried searching for it, but in vain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drag-and-drop using behaviors is very simple.  Download this complete implementation and sample and try it out:

- [ItemsControl Drag Drop Behavior for WPF](http://gallery.expression.microsoft.com/DragDropBehavior/)

Comment: This answer is not useful and the link is dead.

Comment: @bwoogie Indeed, I agree completely. However, I am no longer knowledgeable in WPF to provide a better answer, nor will StackOverflow allow me to delete the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what is a problem if you've already seen how to do drag-n-drop between listboxes on the same window. Use this code or tell us what's wrong with it.

The good thing about drag-n-drop functionality is that control which starts DND operation doesn't have to know anything regarding control which accepts DND result.

Comment: Actually I'm a C# / WPF newbie, I find  WPF simplistic for developing apps. However, I was overwhelmed by the implementation of DND, and was hoping that .NET4 simplified the process, because of the capabilities of newbie friendly XAML . Thanks for the guidance.